# How to use native OS X notification instead of growl in autotest for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, notifications, tdd

Is is possible? I don't want to install Growl for that.

Comment: I don't know much about autotest, and I would suggest you use guard which is great for notifications : https://github.com/guard/guard#system-notifications

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try [terminal-notifier](https://github.com/julienXX/terminal-notifier/tree/master/Ruby#usage) 
or [rspec-nc](https://github.com/twe4ked/rspec-nc#rspec-notification-center) if you are using Rspec